# Javascript Regex.test method gives wrong output on Blackberry OS 4.6

Tags: javascript, regex, blackberry

Below Javascript code checks that given input is alpha numaric or not.
In all the browsers it gives expected output i.e. 'alpha numaric' but on Blackberry OS 4.6 it returns 'No alpha numaric'.

```
var oRegX = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/);

if(!oRegX.test('iAmAlphaNumric123'))
{
    alert('No alpha numaric');
}
else
{
    alert('alpha numaric');
}
```

The code written above is just for example. In reality the regex.test method gives inverse result for any regex and input on Blackberry OS 4.6 browser

I googled about this, but couldn't find any related material to this issue.
Is it a bug in Blackberry OS 4.6 browser or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Makes no sense why you are using `new RegExp` like that. Why are you escaping the `'`?

Comment: Alphanumeric characters includes numbers as well, unless, you only care about letters: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

Comment: @epascarello you are right about escaping the ', but what is wrong in new RegExp?....
krg as I said the code is just for example purpose
I have changed example as per your suggestions

Comment: `var oRegX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;`

Comment: Because the type of the argument in RegExp instantiation call is not usual BB might be trying to compile it or something. Does the same thing happen when you use it like `var oRegX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/` or `var oRegX = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]$');`?